# Mail body with multiple line body

Tags: c#, .net, string, smtp, smtpclient

I'd like to send an email using C#

```
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(_smtp, int.Parse(_port));
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.EnableSsl = bool.Parse(_enableSsl);
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(APIKey, SecretKey);
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.From = _from;
            mail.To.Add(_to);
            mail.Subject = _subject;
            mail.Body = _body;
            if(Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(url, UriKind.Absolute)) mail.Body += "<br/>" + url + "<br/>" + "Cordialement";
            mail.IsBodyHtml = false;

            client.Send(mail);
```

The mail is sent, but its body is received as a single line .

So How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have the following line in your code:

```
mail.Body += "<br/>" + url + "<br/>" + "Cordialement";
```

I'm going to guess that the rest of your `mail.Body` also contains HTML.

If you are placing HTML in the body of the `MailMessage`, you need to set  `IsBodyHtml` to `true` - you have it set to false.

```
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
```